# Manipulate URL segments with jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a website where the user must be able to search a website by tags.
I am using Codeigniter and I think I will be using jQuery for this somehow.

I need the URL to be:

```
http://example.com/keywords/firstkeyword+secondkeyword+thirdkeyword/
```

On the page I got a single search input field and when the user is "adding" a new keyword
I need the URL to be updated when they hit enter but I do not want the page to be reloaded.

So if they add a forth keyword the URL should be:

```
http://example.com/keywords/firstkeyword+secondkeyword+thirdkeyword+forthkeyword/
```

I also need to be able to add other criterias after the keywords segment. For example size.

```
http://example.com/keywords/firstkeyword+secondkeyword+thirdkeyword/size/1+3+4/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This will cause an additional redirect. best solution is to edit your search-script instead.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the URL with Javascript will cause a redirect, unless you manipulate the part after the hash (`#`), which is accessible with `window.location.hash`.

Comment: I will not be using # only URL segments as above.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [HTML5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history)

Nice read, see #3 [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115060278409766341143/posts/ViaVbBMpSVG)